# Static Home Page resets to Front Page

Tags: pages, homepage

I've found many very similar posts but nothing that seems to be exactly like my issue. Unless I've completely not understood how wordpress works.

When I go to Settings >> Reading >> Set Static Home Page (Custom Page)
Save the changes ... my home page is showing my custom page.

Whenever I update a plugin ... this setting changes to show "Front Page" instead of the custom page I had created.

I then have to go back and reconfigure the static page to be the home page again. This is quite inconvenient and makes my site look unprofessional when applying updates if users are viewing my site.

Also if I delete this front page completely (permanent delete) after a plugin update it is recreated and set as the default home page again.

I am pulling my hair out as to why this setting doesn't hold?

Appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: This is a tough one. It sounds like something is changing your setting in the database during a plugin activation hook. I would review your plugins and theme to see if there's something that's updating the option: `show_on_front` or `page_on_front`.

Comment: De-activate all plugins and re-activate , one by one, and notice which plugin's activation change front page option.